# SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input from ajax post call

Tags: json, ajax

I receive "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input" from my ajax post call to send data to my serverlet for processing. Everything appears to actually be working - ajax is sending the data to the servlet, and the servlet is receiving the data correctly. I cannot see why the parser is throwing the error.

I have researched and tried the many other solutions on StackOverFlow without success.

Any help or pointers appreciated!

Cheers...Steve

My browser code is:

```
function createDataset(){
    var jsonObj = new Object();
    jsonObj.display_drivername = document.getElementById('driver_namedb').value;
    jsonObj.drive_seq1 = document.getElementById('drive_seq1').value;
    return jsonObj; 
}

function submit_claim() {
//Main code call
    var JsonDataset = createDataset();
    console.log(JsonDataset);
        request = $.ajax({
            url: '../wp-content/themes/u-design-child/deleteme.php', 
            type: 'POST',
//  Fix - delete this line  contentType:'application/json; charset=utf-8',
//  Fix - delete this line  dataType: 'JSON',
            data: JsonDataset
        }); 
}
```

And serverside test code in deleteme.php:

```
//elog writes to error.log file
if(!empty($_POST['display_drivername'])) {elog ('Drivername found'.$_POST['display_drivername']);};
if(empty($_POST['display_drivername'])) {elog ('driver name empty');};
if(!empty($_POST['drive_seq1'])) {elog ('DSN found'.$_POST['drive_seq1']);};
if(empty($_POST['drive_seq1'])) {elog ('DSN empty');};
```

The result I get is:

Console log output from Submit_Claim (JsonDataset) (expanded in Chrome console):

```
{display_drivername: "Steve Parry [SPAR]", drive_seq1: "2438"}
display_drivername: "Steve Parry [SPAR]"
drive_seq1: "2438"
__proto__: Object
```

Form Data from DeleteMe.php Network Headers:

```
display_drivername: Steve Parry [SPAR]
drive_seq1: 2438
```

Error Log (from Deleteme.php):

```
[06-Jan-2020 18:49:44 UTC] string(34) "Drivername foundSteve Parry [SPAR]"
[06-Jan-2020 18:49:44 UTC] string(13) "DSN found2438"
```

**EDIT 1**: Saw a comment from someone that has now disappeared, pointing out that contenttype should be contentType. Thank you whoever that was, however this hasn't changed the problem.

**EDIT 2** Change the code to reflect the solution

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting it to work perfectly by removing the contentType and dataType lines completely.